# Stand up a ASP.Net Core Web API service in an NUnit Test

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nunit, .net-6.0

I have a NuGet package that I am trying to write some integration tests around.  I am using NUnit to run these tests.

I would like to stand up a basic Web API service using .Net 6.0.  Most of the examples I see require a full project dedicated to running the service.

**Is there a way I can standup a simple Web API service in the `[setup]` of my test?**

It can just run on localhost and only need a single `GET` operation.

Comment: are you trying to test WebAPI or some code which calls this webapi ?

Comment: @CodingMytra - I am trying to test my NuGet that is used with WebAPI services.  (So I ham testing the service)

Comment: check this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/end-to-end-unit-testing-for-net-6-web-api-58883d1b2fe4) which explains how can you test web api.